# Update jQuery plugin to 1.6

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, version

I use a jQuery plugin ([jParallax](http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html)) which works well with jQuery 1.3.2 but not above. 
I need to update it to jQuery 1.6 but have no clue on how to do this.

Is there any document out there that sums up differences between jQuery versions? 
Or anything to help?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to 1.7.1? Upgrading from 1.3 is a major upgrade anyway, so why not go to the newest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> Is there any document out there that sums up differences between
>   jQuery versions?

Click every "Release Notes" link next to versions 1.4 through 1.6...

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery

---

Alternatively, I think it would be easier to use the latest jQuery 1.7 and a different plugin (or write your own plugin from scratch).

http://www.franckmaurin.com/the-parallax-effects-with-jquery/

http://www.davecranwell.com/content/jquery-scroll-parallax-plugin

http://stephenmcintyre.net/blog/jquery-parallax-scrolling/

Comment: Thanks but jParallax is way more powerful for my purpose (multi-axis parallax, easier positionning, mouseport definition, etc).

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm new here and was not familiar with the acceptation system. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read the breaking changes part of the release notes:

[jquery 1.6 Release Notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/)

Comment: @kursus did you ever manage to get jparallax up to spec for the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: The last version of the plugin works fine with latest jQuery, https://github.com/stephband/jparallax

However a bug is introduced in this version : parallax effect is not triggered until you mouse over the viewport. It can be (quite) fixed with the freeze + unfreeze method. 
See https://github.com/stephband/jparallax/issues/26 and some other bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do this, is to check the jQuery Changelog. [Found Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.6/)

Replace the 1.6 in the URL by the version number you want.

For instance, you want to know the differences between jQuery 1.3.2 and 1.6; Therefore you need to check those change-logs (pages):

> [1.4.0](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4/)    January 14, 2010
>   [1.4.1](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.1/)    January 25, 2010
>   [1.4.2](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.2/)    February 19, 2010
>   [1.4.3](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.3/)    October 16, 2010
>   [1.4.4](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.4/)    November 11, 2010
>   [1.5.0](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/)    January 31, 2011
>   [1.5.1](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5.1/)    February 24, 2011
>   [1.5.2](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5.2/)    March 31, 2011
>   [1.6.0](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.6/)   May 3, 2011

Comment: He's already using 1.3.2 so he wouldn't need to see that one.